# Counting two character sequence

Tags: c++

I am new too C++ but have experience in other languages.

I am working through:

**Book:** C++ Primer 5th Ed.
**Exercise:** 5.12

Amongst counting vowels, spaces, and tabs using a switch structure the exercise also asks to keep track of how many times the two character sequences `ff`, `fl`, and `fi` appear in some inputted text. I have seen other solutions to this problem, most using Boolean flag type structures, but I opted to use string iterators to keep track. However being new to C++ I am not sure if there is anything inherently dangerous about my code (ie. iterator pointing to a non valid object). Does this code look okay?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    string text;
    unsigned aCnt = 0, eCnt = 0, iCnt = 0, oCnt = 0, uCnt = 0, spaceCnt = 0, nlCnt = 0, tabCnt = 0, ffCnt = 0, flCnt = 0, fiCnt = 0;
    bool flag = false;

    while (getline(cin, text))
        for (auto it = text.begin(); it != text.end(); ++it) {

            *it = tolower(*it);
            switch (*it) {

            case 'a' :
                ++aCnt;
                break;
            case 'e' :
                ++eCnt;
                break;
            case 'i': 
                if (it != text.begin())
                    if (*(it - 1) == 'f')
                        ++fiCnt;
                    else
                        ++iCnt;
                break;
            case 'o' : 
                ++oCnt;
                break;
            case 'u' : 
                ++uCnt;
                break;
            case ' ':
                ++spaceCnt;
                break;
            case '\n':
                ++nlCnt;
                break;
            case '\t':
                ++tabCnt;
                break;
            case 'f' :
                //Control strucutre that checks if the character pointed to previously was an f.
                if (it != text.begin())
                    if (*(it - 1) == 'f')
                        ++ffCnt;
                break;
            case 'l':
                if (it != text.begin())
                    if (*(it - 1) == 'f')
                        ++flCnt;
                break;
            }

        }

    cout << "The number of 'a' vowels is: \t" << aCnt << endl;
    cout << "The number of 'e' vowels is: \t" << eCnt << endl;
    cout << "The number of 'i' vowels is: \t" << iCnt << endl;
    cout << "The number of 'o' vowels is: \t" << oCnt << endl;
    cout << "The number of 'u' vowels is: \t" << uCnt << endl;
    cout << "The number of tabs read is: \t" << tabCnt << endl;
    cout << "The number of newlines is: \t" << nlCnt << endl;
    cout << "The number of spaces read is: \t" << spaceCnt << endl;
    cout << "The number of 'ff' read is: \t" << ffCnt << endl;
    cout << "The number of 'fl' read is: \t" << flCnt << endl;
    cout << "The number of 'fi' read is: \t" << fiCnt << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this belongs on [codereview.se].

Comment: I would probably use a `std::map<char,unsigned>` to count the occurences to avoid that huge number of oddly named variables

Comment: Though not wrong I recommend adding `{ }` to your `while` loop. It is valid since it is one statement but it could lead to confusion down the road because of how many lines long the `for` loop is inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the normal `for` loop or one of its cousins if you need to modify the container as you go along, access an element more than once, or otherwise iterate in a non-linear fashion through the container.

Range-based `for` is for when you need to access each element of a container once. While you are accessing some elements multiple times which may lead to problems.

You should use `const_iterator` as @SergeyA mentioned.
And insted of modifying `*it` do

```
switch (tolower(*it))
```

Or store it to `temp` variable.

---

Also good practice is to use `map` instad of counter for every `char` or `string` or whatever.

```
std::map<char,unsigned> charCounter;
charCounter['a']++;
```

And instead of `10` `printf()`'s

```
for(auto const & c : charCounter)
{
    for(auto const & i : charCounter.second)
    {
        cout << "The number of " << c << " vowels is: \t" << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`*it = tolower(*it);` is modifying the string in place. I do not think this is what you want to do, as usually counting assumes unmodified incoming sequence. I suggest you use `const_iterator` to prevent yourself from those issues.